# What does mean affinity='precomputed' in Feature Agglomeration dimensionality reduction?

Tags: scikit-learn, feature-extraction, feature-selection, dimensionality-reduction

What does affinity='precomputed' mean in feature agglomeration dimensionality reduction (scikit-learn) and how is it used?
I got much better results than by using other affinity options (such as 'euclidean', 'l1', 'l2' or 'manhattan'), however, I'm not sure what this 'precomputed' actually means and whether I have to provide something "precomputed" to the feature agglomeration algorithm?
What does "precomputed" actually means?

I haven't passed anything other than original data preprocessed (scaled), numpy array. After fit_transform with feature agglomeration, result was passed to Birch clustering algorithm and I got much better results than with other affinities mentioned. Results are comparable with PCA, but  with much lower memory consumption overhead, so I would use feature agglomeration as dimensionality reduction, but I'm concerned that I did it wrong?

Comment: Yes, you can provide a precomputed distance matrix:
https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/bac89c2/sklearn/cluster/hierarchical.py#L769

Comment: I haven't passed any "precomputed distance matrix", just scaled data (numpy array) and got pretty good results with clustering. What was used as "precomputed"?

Comment: let me know if my answer helps

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/users/5025009/seralouk, so distance matrix is actual data itself?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Nice question.

### `affinity == 'precomputed'` means that the flatten array containing the upper triangular of the `distance matrix` of the original data is used.

Reference ([source code](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/bac89c2/sklearn/cluster/hierarchical.py#L454)):

> ```
>     if affinity == 'precomputed':
>         # for the linkage function of hierarchy to work on precomputed
>         # data, provide as first argument an ndarray of the shape returned
>         # by pdist: it is a flat array containing the upper triangular of
>         # the distance matrix.
>         i, j = np.triu_indices(X.shape[0], k=1)
>         X = X[i, j]
>     elif affinity == 'l2':
>         # Translate to something understood by scipy
>         affinity = 'euclidean'
>     elif affinity in ('l1', 'manhattan'):
>         affinity = 'cityblock'
> ```

Comment: An the "distance matrix" is the data itself or what?

Comment: it's the distance matrix of the original data. see here for details: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distance_matrix